# Convert TImage to black and white

Tags: firemonkey

Is there a way to convert a color `TImage` to black and white, with no Effect component involved?

My `TImage` contains one `TCheckbox` as a child. If I add a `MonochromeEffect` to the `TImage`, the child `TCheckbox` becomes unresponsive.